# jQuery get text for jQuery 'IF' statements

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the TEXT from within a span class for jQuery `if` statements. For example, if I have something like:

```
if ($('input:radio[name=SELECT___ENG___57]:checked').val() == '1191') {
$("[class^=eng_]").css( "display", "none" );}
```

I want the "ENG" in `input:radio[name=SELECT___ENG___57]:checked` to be a dynamic value from `<span class="product_code">ENG</span>` (elsewhere on the same page)

so basically if `<span class="product_code">IMANOOB</span>` How would I get my jQuery to be

```
if ($('input:radio[name=SELECT___IMANOOB___57]:checked').val() == '1191') {
$("[class^=eng_]").css( "display", "none" );}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are messing up with selectors up there, just use a pseudo selector like $('span:contains("somevalue")')

Comment: Can you post a representative sample of your HTML? This might illustrate your problem better than your explanation (though, please: try and improve the explanation as well). If you're able, include a live demo in your question (see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not sure if i understand the question exactly, but if you are trying to make part of the select query depend the text in span, then do something like this.

```
var productCode = $(".product_code").text();

if ($('input:radio[name=SELECT___'+productCode+'___57]:checked').val() == '1191') {
$("[class^=eng_]").css( "display", "none" );}
```

I dont know how the span product code is set and where it gets its value, but wherever you set the value for span, you should refresh/re-call the selector function to update your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can check only the beggining of the name like this :

```
if ($('input:radio[name^=SELECT___]:checked').val() == '1191') {
$("[class^=eng_]").css( "display", "none" );}
```

Therefore, `SELECT___ENG___57`, `SELECT___IMANOOB___57` or `SELECT___TEST` will match and return a value

Answer (score 0):

use below code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var product_code = $('.product_code').text();
    if ($('input:radio[name=SELECT___'+ product_code +'___57]:checked').val() == '1191') {
        alert('fired');
        $("[class^=eng_]").css( "display", "none" );
    }
});
```

here is [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jj165gvc/)